# Why are solutions in the wrong order?

Tags: prolog

I have been asked to

> define a predicate `subseq/2`, with signature `subseq(-,+)`,
> which is true when both its arguments are lists, and its first
> argument can be constructed by removing zero or more elements
> from its second argument.

... with intended solution order:

```
?- subseq(X, [a, b, c]).
X = [a, b, c] ;
X = [a, b] ;
X = [a, c] ;
X = [a] ;
X = [b, c] ;
X = [b] ;
X = [c] ;
X = [].
```

My code:

```
subseq([], []).
subseq([], [_|_]).
subseq([X|XS], [X|YS]) :- subseq(XS, YS).
subseq([X|XS], [_|YS]) :- subseq([X|XS], YS).
```

My code's solution order:

```
?- subseq(X, [a, b, c]).
X = []
X = [a]
X = [a, b]
X = [a, b, c]
X = [a, c]
X = [b]
X = [b, c]
X = [c] ;
false.
```

How do I achieve the intended solution order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Prolog, the order of the rules is crucial. To get the desired output, simply change the order of the rules, like this:

```
subseq([X|XS], [X|YS]) :- subseq(XS, YS).
subseq([X|XS], [_|YS]) :- subseq([X|XS], YS).
subseq([], []).
subseq([], [_|_]).

?- subseq(X,[a,b,c]).
X = [a, b, c]
X = [a, b]
X = [a, c]
X = [a]
X = [b, c]
X = [b]
X = [c]
X = []
```

Comment: One should note, though, that changing the order of clauses can also result in unintended/unexpected behavior, especially if arguments aren't bound as expected. For instance, evaluating `subseq(Xs,Ys).` will result in infinite recursion if both `Xs` and `Ys` are unbound.

Answer (score 0):

Little tweaks can change the order:

```
sub_list_forwards(Sub, Long) :-
    sub_list_forwards_(Long, Sub).

sub_list_forwards_([], []).
% Either pick H, or don't
sub_list_forwards_([H|T], S) :-
    (S = Sub ; S = [H|Sub]),
    sub_list_forwards_(T, Sub).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- sub_list_forwards(S, [a,b,c]).
S = [] ;
S = [c] ;
S = [b] ;
S = [b, c] ;
S = [a] ;
S = [a, c] ;
S = [a, b] ;
S = [a, b, c].
```

Or tweak the selection line to be:

```
    (S = [H|Sub] ; S = Sub),
```

... which results in the order you were given:

```
?- sub_list_forwards(S, [a,b,c]).
S = [a, b, c] ;
S = [a, b] ;
S = [a, c] ;
S = [a] ;
S = [b, c] ;
S = [b] ;
S = [c] ;
S = [].
```

Note that neither of these leave an *unwanted choicepoint* at the end, because they use first-argument indexing on `[]` vs `[H|T]` with 1 selection each.

Does the order matter? What would be an optimum order? It probably varies.

In general it is best to put the base case (i.e. `[], []`) *first*, for flexibility (and because they sometimes contain a cut).

This is programming, rather than mathematics, so *meaningful* variable names/initials are far better for readability than using the likes of X and Y continually.

Using `(S = [H|Sub] ; S = Sub),` produces the sensible:

```
?- nth1(5, L, e), sub_list_forwards([a,b,c], L).
L = [a, b, c, _, e] ;
L = [a, b, c, _, e, _] ;
L = [a, b, c, _, e, _, _] ;
L = [a, b, c, _, e, _, _, _] ;
```

... rather than a stack overflow, and so is preferable.